# Redirect port :2082 with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cpanel, whm

I have did numerous searches and also saw numerous results, nothing works actually.

Anyway, what I wanted to do is redirect port 2083 to a different URL, say an IP with port 1234, 127.0.0.0:1234 (this is for cpanel btw) when accessed like:

```
domain.com:2083
```

It should redirect to:

```
127.0.0.1:1234
```

I'm already redirecting domain.com/cpanel to an example of 127.0.0.1 shown above with following piece of code in my htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /cpanel(.*) http://127.0.0.1:1234/$1
```

but just this port is not getting to work.

Basically, what I wanted to do is disable logging to cpanel/WHM through domain.com and just allow through the server IP, but I guess that's not possible due the the web server I've configured in a way to act as a proxy server, so what I could do is redirect domain.com:2082 to the original server IP.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That does not work for cPanel because cPanel is listening on port 2083, not Apache. I recommend using iptables rules to accomplish your goal:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2083 -j REJECT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2083 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

The order that these commands are ran matter, since iptables rules are processed in order.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I use CSF and am not that good or pro you can say at IP tables, so before I proceed to run those commands, how can, if I wish to undo it on a later stage, do so? :)

Comment: The command `iptables -F` will flush all iptables rules. `/etc/init.d/iptables reload` will reload saved rules. CSF is likely different, so consult your documentation.

Comment: I do have a lot of ip tables rules, mostly CSF IP blocks and flush would remove them all. Is there a specific way through SSH or such by which we could enter the saved command list and I can remove those? Thank you.

Comment: Consult your CSF documentation for how to add and remove rules.

Comment: I did added those two rules (replacing 127.0.0.1 with my sever IP) by creating precsf.sh and postcsf.sh for custom iptable rules following this tutorial: http://sachinpradeeplinux.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/add-custom-iptables-rule-to-csf/

But still it doesn't get to work, Also wrote rewrite condition in htaccess:

    RewriteCond ${SERVER_PORT} 2082
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://127.0.0.1:2083/$1 [QSA,L]

but still not getting to work. Any ideas or workarounds or maybe the mistake I'm making?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, anyone has answer to it? Thank you.

Comment: I got that to work, but just one thing which is not working. Right now, it's blocking access through domain as well as IP, but I need it to be accessible with IP address, but it's blocking it too. Any alterations to above rules perhaps?